# On actually computing with the cellular method (solid state band structure)

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

(This question is, essentially, about understanding the last paragraph on page 187 in Ashcroft and Mermin, but I here provide context for those who don't have the book at their disposal.)

In the cellular method, instead of exactly solving the $H$ eigenvalue equation for one-electron eigenstates with true (to the extent that we can make a mean-field approximation at all) potential $U$, one replaces $U$ with a spherical potential $V$ (e.g. the atomic potential, if the crystal is monatomic -- presumably this method doesn't work well if we have nontrivial bases at each lattice point) and it can be shown that the method then essentially says to solve
$$\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V(\mathbf{r}) \right)\psi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r}) = \varepsilon(\mathbf{k}) \psi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r})$$
subject to the boundary conditions in a given primitive unit cell (usually taken as the WS cell) which enforce continuity of the wavefunction and its derivative, while sprinkling in Bloch's theorem:
$$\psi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r}) = e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\psi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R})$$
and
$$\hat{\mathbf{n}}(\mathbf{r}) \cdot \nabla \psi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r}) = e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\hat{\mathbf{n}}(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R}) \cdot \nabla\psi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R})$$
where $\hat{\mathbf{n}}(\mathbf{r})$ denotes the local normal to the unit cell.

The spherical structure of the problem means that we can take solutions of the well-known form from atomic physics involving spherical harmonics and solution to an effective radial equation which emerges from making the ansatz:
$$\psi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r},\varepsilon) = \sum_{l,m} A_{l,m}Y_{l,m}(\theta,\phi)\chi_{l,\varepsilon(\mathbf{k})}.$$

Now finally I can come to the crux of my question. A&M say that to actually solve for the $A_{l,m}$ one truncates the sum at some large $l$, to begin. Then they say

> Since there is only a finite number of coefficients in the expansion, we can, for a general cell, fit the boundary condition only at a finite set of points on its surface.

No problem, I can accept that on intuitive grounds. But they then say:

> The imposition of this finite set of boundary conditions (chosen to be as many as there are unknown coefficients) leads to a set of $\mathbf{k}$-dependent linear homogeneous equations for the $A_{lm}$ and the values of $\varepsilon$ for which the determinant of these equations vanishes are the required energies $\varepsilon(\mathbf{k})$.

Perhaps my linear algebra is rusty, but I utterly could not follow this. Suppose we kept $M$ terms in the aforementioned step. Then in saying "chosen to be as many as there are unknown coefficients", A&M are telling us to pick $M$ points $\mathbf{r}_i$ on the primitive cell boundary and to apply each of our *two* boundary conditions at each $\mathbf{r}_i$; that is, we are led to $2M$ equations for our solution to satisfy, and yet there are only $M$ coefficients $A_{lm}$. How then is this not undetermined? Or is this the point/I have understood correctly, and it is the vanishing of the determinant in this $2M \times M$ matrix problem which leads to the discrete set of solutions?